# Twilio allow outoing or incoming voice call to a specific client only

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am setting up a programmable voice token with the following codes:

```
const accessToken = new AccessToken(config.accountSid, config.apiKey, config.apiSecret);
accessToken.identity = user_uid;

if (identity === "caller") {
  var grant = new VoiceGrant({
    outgoingApplicationSid: config.twimlAppSid,
    incomingAllow: false,
  });
}
else if (identity === "callee") {
  var grant = new VoiceGrant({
    incomingAllow: true,
  });
}
accessToken.addGrant(grant);

return resolve(JSON.stringify({ token: accessToken.toJwt() }));
```

If the user is a caller, then I allow outgoing calls, but not incoming. If the user is a callee, then I allow incoming only. What I am trying to add more to the token generation is that the caller can only call one designated user, and the callee can only receive from one designated user.

In another words, is that possible to do that when generating the AccessToken such that:

```
      var grant = new VoiceGrant({
        outgoingApplicationSid: config.twimlAppSid,
        outgoingClient: "client1",
        incomingAllow: false,
      });
     accessToken.addGrant(grant);
```

So the access above can only call `client1` and nobody else. By the same token:

```
      var grant = new VoiceGrant({
        incomingAllow: true,
        incomingclient: "client2"
      });
     accessToken.addGrant(grant);
```

So the access above can only receive calls from `client2` and nobody else?
The codes above are hypothetical, and I am trying to implement something similiar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set identity and inbound for the [Access Token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) but you want to place the logic on the backend on how calls can be placed. This is the Application SID (which points to a Voice URL) you defined in the token. You backend code can determine what do do based on client identity.

Comment: Hi @Alan, I am not sure that I understand your answer. Could you provide some specific codes or examples to support the answer?